# Reduce font size in email apps (default + outlook)

Tags: email

I have got lumia 1020 running Windows Phone 8.1 on AT&T. I have been an Android user (Galaxy S3 and S5) and though Windows Phone provide much better and faster experience overall, I am really concerned about the bigger fonts in email client compared to their android couter parts.

I would like to scan the more no. of emails in single sight and therefore would like to have Inbox and content view with smaller fonts compared to the

Comment: Can you finish your thought so someone knows exactly how to help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the basic font size in **Settings** -> **ease of access** > **Font Size**. This changes the text size in People, phone, email, messaging, lock screen and some web pages.